# set Expire for element in an Array in mongoose (not for whole collection or for whole array)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose,
I want to delete the element in an array after sometime, not the whole collection or array.
Example:

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: {
    type: String,
    select: false
  },
  refreshTokens: [
    {
      type: String,
      select: false,
    }
  ]
 
});
```

I want to set expire for element in refreshTokens. **Not for the entire refreshTokens**

Comment: You have to write a custom application to do this.

Answer (score 0):

to set a time delay after which you want to update the record inside the refresh token you can use `setInterval(foo, <delay>)`

an in order to update the value you can use [updateOne function from mongoose](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

```
db.collection.update(query, update, options)
```

now you can set the `obj.refreshToken.type = ""` and `obj.refreshToken.select = false`